# Why using two or more fragments in the same Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I am a beginner android developer, and right now I'm learning about fragments in android, and so and as I read that :

> A fragment is just a part of an activity. You can have a fragment that
>   takes up part of a screen or a whole screen. Or you can show multiple
>   fragments at the same time to make up a whole screen. Within an
>   activity, you can also swap out different fragments with each other.
>   (You can also have invisible fragments as well, that do some work
>   related to the activity, but we won’t cover those in this course.)
>
> Fragments were introduced in Android when we started building for
>   larger screen devices like tablets. Let me show you an example.
>
> In the master/detail pattern, a list fragment is on the left side of
>   the screen, while the detail fragment on the right swaps out depending
>   on the list item selected.

So, I'm asking what's the utility of fragments apart from adapting to larger screens?
Thanks !!

Comment: here is one of a long list of existing questions that cover this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756999/why-should-i-use-fragment-in-android. Just google it next time

Comment: @TimCastelijns i googled it but i wanted a simple answer from someone advanced , as i'm beginner i can not understand everything that comes here in your link

Comment: Usage of fragments explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597908/9744898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Source : [developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly about reusable UI and self-contained code.

In a bigger project these can come in handy.

Also you can dynamically configure whats on the screen based on settings, maybe a/b testing, remote configuration etc. without lots of rewritten code. Team members can work independently on code parts if they are self-contained. Components can be tested in other activities, with different configurations.

So it really dependes on your use case.